# using numpy.where on multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array, each row represents an output of a classifier that classifies some input to 3 categories (array size is `1000 * 3`) :

```
0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 1.0
1.0 0.3 0.3
0.3 0.3 0.3
0.3 1.0 0.3
...
```

I want to get a list of all the inputs that the classifier is "not sure" about them.
And I'm defining "not sure" as no category is above 0.8.

To solve it I use :

```
np.where(model1_preds.max(axis=1) < 0.8)
```

This works great.

But now I have 6 classifiers (that have analyzed the same inputs in the same order), and an array `6 * 1000 * 3` representing their results.

I want to find 2 things:

1. All the inputs that at least one classifier was "not sure" about.
2. All the inputs that all the classifier were "not sure" about.

I assume the general direction is something like this :

```
np.stack(np.where(model_preds.max(axis=1) < 0.8) for model_preds in all_preds)
```

But it won't work because python don't know what I mean in the for loop.

Comment: Is your matrix already a 6x1000x3? Or is it a *list* of six 1000x3 matrices?

Comment: It is already 6 * 1000 * 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively to `np.where`:

```
res_all_unsure = preds[:,np.amax(preds, axis=(0,2)) <= 0.8,:]
res_one_unsure = preds[:,preds.max(-1).min(0) <= 0.8,:]
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is already a **6×1000×3 matrix `preds`**, you can first `np.transpose()` it into a 1000×6×3 matrix.

```
y = preds.transpose(1,0,2)  # preds is the input matrix, 6x1000x3
```

Next we can turn it into a 1000×6 matrix where for each experiment and for each classifier, we know whether all the values were less than `0.8` by stating:

```
y = np.all(y<0.8,axis=2)
```

Finally we can use another `np.all()` to verify where **all** the classifiers were unsure:

```
all_classifiers_unsure = np.where(np.all(y,axis=1))  # all classifiers
```

Or where **any** of the classifiers was unsure:

```
any_classifier_unsure = np.where(np.any(y,axis=1))   # any of the classifiers
```

We can write it shorter like:

```
experiment_classifier = np.all(preds.transpose(1,0,2) < 0.8,axis=2)
all_classifiers_unsure = np.where(np.all(experiment_classifier,axis=1))
any_classifier_unsure = np.where(np.any(experiment_classifier,axis=1))
```

Although I am quite confident, please validate by checking a few indices (ones that are true and ones that are not true).

**EDIT**

You can still use your proposed method of `.max() < 0.8`, but with `axis=2`:

```
experiment_classifier = preds.transpose(1,0,2).max(axis=2) < 0.8
all_classifiers_unsure = np.where(np.all(experiment_classifier,axis=1))
any_classifier_unsure = np.where(np.any(experiment_classifier,axis=1))
```